# ¿Cómo crear una consulta con contador de registro?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

¿Cómo puedo crear en UNA sola consulta en donde me devuelva la primera columna con el contador de registro? O en otras palabras ¿Cómo puedo enumerar los resultados de un solo select?

Ejemplo:

```
---------------------------
  No. | Nombre
---------------------------
   1  | Jose Vaca Cipres
---------------------------
   2  | Jesus Gonzales
---------------------------
   3  | Edgar Hernandez
---------------------------
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Utilizando una variable personalizada:

```
SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 ‘nro’,  nombre 
FROM tabla t, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r
```

Comment: Buena respuesta. [Acá](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/48aae/2) dejo un fiddle para que el OP lo pueda ver en funcionamiento (demora un poco en  cargar).

Comment: ¡Funciona, muchas gracias! Solo una duda, ¿Qué significa esa t y esa r en la consulta?

Comment: Las letras t y r son alias que se utilizan cuando utilizas más de una tabla para referenciarlas. Si lo quitas no funciona y verás que MySQL te pide que los identifiques con un alias. Puedes asignarles el nombre que desees.

Comment: no me funciono ese codigo me tira error en el FROM (select) porque dice que no puede hacer un select dentro del from

Comment: @Kriker revisa [Google][http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-row_number/]

Answer (score 1):

De esta forma puedes obtener el conteo de lo registros que requieras

```
SET @numero=0;
SELECT @numero:=@numero+1 AS `posicion`, `Emails`.* FROM `Emails`;
```

Puedes apoyarte del siguiente enlace para mayor informacion.
http://totaki.com/poesiabinaria/2013/01/numerar-los-resultados-de-un-select-en-mysql/

Comment: Hola Raul. Técnicamente, no es *una sola consulta*, porque se necesita el `SET` antes de hacer la consulta para que funcione correctamente.

Answer (score 1):

Cuando utilizas una consulta la sentencia con `INNER` , `ORDER BY` , `LIMIT` cambia el contador

```
SELECT (@REG:= @REG+1) AS cont,p.`Emails`,p.`descripcion`, p.idpersona
from persona p
INNER JOIN ciudad c on c.idpersona=p.idpersona
ORDER BY p.`descripcion` ASC LIMIT 10,10;
```